# zend autoloader doesn't work in doctrine2 models

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, autoloader

i'm try to use Zend_Paginator class in my Doctrine2 repository, but php doesn't see this class, it try to find it in Doctrine autoloader paths, why standart zend autoloading doesn't use?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put these two lines of code before using any of ZF component as library

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```